# Base R plot legend from different df than plot, help needed

Tags: r, loops, plot

First time posting a question and relatively new to R, so bear with me please. Im building a loop that will take 2 columns at a time to calculate symmetric pivot coordinates (isometric log-ratios) from around 50 variables and produces one xy plot per loop. I have two questions regarding to the plotting. 1) I managed to get loop working and plot diagrams using base R plot, with colored sample points based on variable in column 1 (Cluster). I am struggling with the legend as while it takes the names of the cluster from the column but the colors are not produced expect for one cluster. Any help? 2) I would prefer using ggplot in this loop but it is not working, can anybody help with that? So the loop will create dataframe Z with two columns with calculated pivot coordinated from two variables in df. In the plot, these variables are plotted from Z but will need to get the names from df along with points colored based on column 1 in df.

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
df_syn <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=50, min=1, max=20), nrow=10)) 
names(df_syn) <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
df_cr <- data.frame(Cluster=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'))
df_syn <- cbind(df_cr, df_syn)
D <- ncol(df_syn[, 2:6])
for (i in 2:D) {
  for (j in 2:D) {
    if (i == j) {
      plot(0, 0, type="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
      text(0, 0, names(df_syn[i]))
    } else {
      Z <- robCompositions::pivotCoord(df_syn[, c(i, j, 2:D[-c(i, j)])], method="symm")
      plot(Z[, 1:2], 
           xlab=paste(colnames(df_syn[i])), ylab=paste(colnames(df_syn[j])), col=factor(df_syn$Cluster), pch=19)
      legend("bottomright", legend=unique(df_syn[, 1]), pch=19, ncol=1, col=factor(df_syn$Cluster))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Imagine somebody pasting your code into a script. It doesn't work. Please make this reproducible, it's easy, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I edited the code that it should now work if somebody tries. The problem is the same, legend color for the point is in only one Cluster group, others are in black. Also if somebody knows how to insert proper ggplot script to produce the diagrams, it would be very helpful. So far, I havent been able to get it to work. Also, you need package RobCompositions for this in order for pivotCoord to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an easy fix. You specified `col=factor(df_syn$Cluster)`, which gives `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2`, and since just the first three elements are needed, you get black, black, red. What you want ist `unique(factor(df_syn$Cluster))`.

```
par(mfrow=c(D - 1, D - 1))
for (i in 2:D) {
  for (j in 2:D) {
    if (i == j) {
      plot(0, 0, type="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
      text(0, 0, names(df_syn[i]))
    } else {
      Z <- robCompositions::pivotCoord(df_syn[, c(i, j, 2:D[-c(i, j)])], method="symm")
      plot(Z[, 1:2], 
           xlab=paste(colnames(df_syn[i])), ylab=paste(colnames(df_syn[j])), col=factor(df_syn$Cluster), pch=19)
      legend("bottomright", legend=unique(df_syn[, 1]), pch=19, ncol=1, col=unique(factor(df_syn$Cluster)))
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it now works perfectly! Any tips for using ggplot instead of base R. I tried ```ggplot(Z[, 1:2], aes(x=df_syn[, i], y=df_syn[, j], colour=df_syn[,1])+geom_point()```, also I found somewhere that ggplot in a loop requires print() command, but it did not work either.

Comment: @jukkaper ggplot is overrated, I never use it.